# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker marks input $invalid after editing even it's correct

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Standard date field with datepicker-popup from UI Bootstrap.
Setting date programmatically - no problem. But after ANY change it is marked as $invalid and stays $invalid even format is correct and I edit it to previous value (which was correct in the beginning). Why?

```
<form name="form">
        <input name="testDatepicker"
               ng-model="testDatepicker"
               placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy"
               datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy"/>

        <div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"
             ng-show="form.testDatepicker.$dirty && form.testDatepicker.$invalid">
           Invalid date
        </div>
</form>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/mug2e381/

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a bug in UI Bootstrap: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3835

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the version to the latest one. It has at least been resolved in version 0.14.3.